# Regular Expression, match characters between { }

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find text that contains a < or > between { }. This is within HTML and I'm having trouble getting it to be "ungreedy".

So I want to find text that matches these strings:

```
{test > 3}
{testing >= 3 : comment}
{example < 4}
```

I've tried a number of regular expressions, but the all seem to continue past the closing } and including HTML that has < or >. For example, I tried this regex

```
{.*?(<|>).*?}
```

but that ends up matching text like this:

```
{if true}<b>testing</b>{/if}
```

It seems pretty simple, any text between { } that contain < or >.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
{[^}]*(<|>).*}
```

Comment: I up-voted, but you really need to make the .* match lazy or replace it with another [^}]* to avoid problems with greedyness if there will ever be multiple sets on the same line.

Comment: You'd need the ungreedy modifier, otherwise the first character class will gobble up everything up until the first `}` character...

Comment: just added a ? after .* to make it greedy and it works correctly with multiple matches on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

An even more efficient regex (because there is no non-greedy matching):

```
'#{[^}<>]*[<>]+[^}]*}#'
```

The reason there aren't brackets in the third character class is so that it matches strings with more than one > (such as `{foo <> bar}`...

Answer (score 0):

```
{[^}]*?(<|>)[^{]*?}
```

Try that. Note that I replaced the `.`s with a character class that means everything except the left/right curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Ungreedy (U) switch?